# Angular 2 Template Parsing Error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am getting a parsing error when compiling my angular 2 app (version 2.4.1)

> assets/app/app.component.ts(13,42): error TS1125: Hexadecimal digit
>   expected

the code is

```
<ul>                   
    <li><a routerLink='\usaddchild'>Add Child</a></li>
</ul>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

and the line is specific that is causing issues is below

```
<li><a routerLink='\usaddchild'>Add Child</a></li>
```

there seems to be an an issue with the \us.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your slashes is in the wrong direction. Correct:

```
<li><a routerLink='/usaddchild'>Add Child</a></li>
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Angular2 thinks it's some kind of unicode character, which do start with `\u`:
http://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/unicode-characters.htm